# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have created a meteor app and cloned [houston](https://github.com/gterrono/houston). I run meteor from the path app/houston, the following error appears.

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'
W20150316-16:02:33.273(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/houston/package.js:3:9
W20150316-16:02:33.273(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/houston/package.js:76:3
W20150316-16:02:33.273(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/garima.wadhera/houston_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
W20150316-16:02:33.273(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150316-16:02:33.274(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/admin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.yumiah++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150316-16:02:33.274(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/garima.wadhera/houston_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:116:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Where Am I making a mistake? Please guide.

For reference: [houston code](https://github.com/gterrono/houston)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The houston package at https://github.com/gterrono/houston is a meteor package not a meteor project. It runs if you add it as a package in an existing meteor project.

You have to add the package to another meteor project.

```
meteor create project
cd project
meteor add houston:admin
```

Then you can load it up at `/admin` on your web browser.

If you want to edit the code create a directory called `packages` clone the package into that and `meteor remove houston:admin` (if you added it above) and add it back with `meteor add houston:admin` (will add the local one)